# Align Property is not working in ListView in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want one of my Menu item to be placed at the bottom the Drawer Menu(Specifically Logout, to be at the bottom of the Menu). I'm trying to use Align widget but not able to do so, even I've tried wrapping it inside Expanded widget after watching many solutions but still not able to fix it.

Here is my Code:

```
    drawer: Drawer(

            child: Expanded(
              child: ListView(
                padding:  EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                children: <Widget>[
                  UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black),
                    accountName: _userName!=null?Text(_userName,):Container(),
                    accountEmail: _userNumber!=null?Text(_userNumber):Container(),
                    currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundColor:
                      Theme.of(context).platform == TargetPlatform.iOS
                          ? Colors.blue
                          : Colors.white,
                      child:_userName!=null? Text(
                        "${_userName[0]}",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40.0,color: Colors.black),
                      ):Container(),
                    ),
                  ),
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: (){
                      print('Home');
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text("Home",),
                      leading: Icon(Icons.home,color: Colors.black,),
                    ),
                  ),
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: (){
                      print('My Orders');
                      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context)=>OrderScreen(Pin:_userPin,Number:_userNumber)
                      ));

                    },
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text("My Orders"),
                      leading: Icon(Icons.fastfood,color: Colors.black,),
                    ),
                  ),
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: (){
                      print('My Address');
                

                    },
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text("My Address"),
                      leading: Icon(Icons.location_on,color: Colors.black,),
                    ),
                  ),
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: (){
                      print('My Cart');
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                     
                      
                    },
                    child:
                    ListTile(
                      title: Text("My Cart"),
                      leading: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart,color: Colors.black,),
                    ),
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text("Help"),
                    leading: Icon(Icons.help,color: Colors.black,),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Text("Logout"), //<-- I want this to be at the bottom.
                        leading: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app,color: Colors.black,),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check out this example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Sample app'),),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: Column(
         
          children: <Widget>[
            UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black),
              accountName: Text('Username'),
              accountEmail: Text('UserEmail'),
              currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor:
                    Theme.of(context).platform == TargetPlatform.iOS
                        ? Colors.blue
                        : Colors.white,
                child: Text(
                  "sample name",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0, color: Colors.black),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                print('Home');
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  "Home",
                ),
                leading: Icon(
                  Icons.home,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                print('My Orders');
                /* Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context)=>OrderScreen(Pin:_userPin,Number:_userNumber)
                    )); */
              },
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text("My Orders"),
                leading: Icon(
                  Icons.fastfood,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                print('My Address');
              },
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text("My Address"),
                leading: Icon(
                  Icons.location_on,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                print('My Cart');
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text("My Cart"),
                leading: Icon(
                  Icons.shopping_cart,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text("Help"),
              leading: Icon(
                Icons.help,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: ListTile(
                  title:
                      Text("Logout"), //<-- I want this to be at the bottom.
                  leading: Icon(
                    Icons.exit_to_app,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: Text('Sample'),
    ));
  }
}
```

Change this according to your data and just replace the listview with the Column widget.

And Let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi @Sagar Acharya, still not able fix it. I've replaced ListView with Column but got no change in UI.

Comment: Have you checked out the code that I have added just copy paste because I am able to get the out put as you said Logout at the bottom. Just check it out and let me know.

Comment: Copy and paste did the trick. Even though I'm not able to distinguish the difference between  both codes, like where I was doing wrong. But yes, your code is working. Thank you so much.